# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout works wrong

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I make a layout with `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `Toolbar`. and I add fragments with `drawerLayout`, and `setTitle` with `collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("title")`.
But some pages works well, some works wrong.

I don't know why. Could anyone help me?

EDIT:

I found that error occurs when replace fragments with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` collapsed.

xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contents_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: okay]

[image: wrong]

Comment: Try by giving `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: I don't know when `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` works like below.

Comment: I found that when I replace fragments when `CollapsingToolbarLayout` collapsed.

Comment: can you please post your style.xml and manifest.xml because It's theme problem. your code is fine.

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never hardcoded the value of appbarlayout make it wrap content for the reference just have a look at the XML code below that would help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_ffffff"
    tools:context=".activity.profile.ProfileActivity">>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transaparent_color">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <include layout="@layout/myparallaxview" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15"
                android:text="Chine Owhaigi"
                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16"
                app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoRegular" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/user_contact_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5"
                android:text="7080644084"
                android:textColor="@color/rechcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16"
                app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoRegular" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_25">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="245dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_card"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/account_detail_card" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/add_money_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/edit_account" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_40"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_20"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/ecashBalance"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_13"
                        app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoRegular" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/cash_balance_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="2000000"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_33"
                        app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_saved_cards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_60"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_30"
                android:background="@color/color_f5f6f8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/saved_cards"
                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16"
                app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoRegular" />

            <include layout="@layout/profile_seprator" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_60"
                android:background="@color/color_f5f6f8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/reset_mpin"
                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16"
                app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoRegular" />

            <include layout="@layout/profile_seprator" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_60"
                android:background="@color/color_f5f6f8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_16"
                app:decorTypefaceAsset="@string/robotoRegular" />

            <include layout="@layout/profile_seprator" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code I have done this, you can refer. it will help you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initToolbar();
        initAllWidgets();

    }
    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
    private void initAllWidgets() {

        //setting toolbar properties;
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //setup root layout

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Abdul Rizwan");

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"

            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsableTitle"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contents_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsableTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/collapsable_title_size</item>

</style>

<dimen name="collapsable_title_size">26dp</dimen>
```

**color.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```